# Perform join using latitude and longitude in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I have an excel spreadsheet with the latitude and longitude of bike docking stations.
I have a shape file in R (cb_2018_17_bg_500k.shp) that has GEOID (12 digit FIPS code) column and a column labelled geometry. The values in this column are POLYGON((longitude,latitude))
I am trying to add a column in the excel spreadsheet titled FIPS. So, I need to somehow join the latitude and longitude to GEOID column in the shape file.
I am a novice when it comes to R.
Any advice will be much appreciated.
Rich

So far, I have only managed to upload the shape file to R.

Comment: Please have a look for simillar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74087315/latitude-longitude-to-nuts3-in-r/74088890#74088890. When you manage to have excel data in R as a data.frame, you can convert it to `sf` object with `sf::st_to_sf()` function, then do a spatial join with polygons using `sf::st_join()`.

Comment: Many thanks. Unfortunately, I get this error: 'st_to_sf' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sf' when I try sf::st_to_sf(myexcel data.frame)

Comment: Please share the code you've used so far. Include the error. And `dput(head( __ ))` where __ is the name of the data you're using. It sounds like you have two data objects, one a shapefile and the other is something from an excel file? So you need to provide `dput` for both.

Comment: I made some progress with: mysf <- st_as_sf(x = myexcel, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"). But the resulting geometry column contains POINTS (Lon,lat) while the geometry column in my shape file is POLYGON(Lon, lat). Thoughts?

Comment: First of all, sorry for mistake, `sf::st_as_sf` obviously. As you already have `mysf` spatial points and `mypolygons` as spatial polygons you can `sf::st_join()` them like: `mysf |> sf::st_join(mypolygons)`. In result you should have `mysf` (points dataframe) with all the columns from `mypolygons`.

Comment: Much appreciated. I tried this: st_join(mypolygons, mysf) and got this error: Error in st_geos_binop("intersects", x, y, sparse = sparse, prepared = prepared,  : 
  st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE

Comment: `st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE` says that coordinate reference systems of those 2 objects you are trying to join are different and you should first transform one to match another, something like `mysf <- st_transform(mysf, crs = st_crs(mypolygons))`

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work either. All the advice much appreciated. I will do this the old fashioned way, by hand. Best.